# Can a (double variable) $$variable access class property?

Tags: php

What scopes, for lack of a better term, are available to a `$$var` inside of a class function? (What are the limits and abilities of the `$$var` syntax?)

```
class foo{
    private $bar = 'class property';

    function bizz($string)
    {
        $bang = 'method prop';
        echo $$string;
    }
}

$f = new foo();
$f->bizz('bar'); //error
$f->bizz('this->bar'); //error
$f->bizz('bang'); //'method prop'
$f->bizz('string'); //'string'
```

Is there any way to reference a variable or method that has a non-local scope with this syntax?

I do know that `$this->$string` would be able to access the class property, but I am wondering specifically about the `$$var` syntax and its limits and abilities.

> **EDIT** I found this on the documentation for php after posting the question - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
>
> > **Warning**
> >
> > Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

(I had a hard time searching for this question on here, so I am not sure if this question has been asked before)

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, it can't. Your code boils down to trying to access an undefined local variable `$bang`, not the `$this->bang` defined as a class attribute.

You'd need

```
function bizz($string) {
    echo $this->{$string};
}
```

instead